# Readback of writes via an mmap mapped region returns wrong values

Tags: linux, caching, arm, mmap, virtual-address-space

I am working on a Zynq board with custom FPGA design, where I have some Block Memories and I want read/write to them from software running on ARM. I have used `mmap` to map the address space of the block memory to user space from `/dev/mem`. I write a chunk of data (less than one kernel page) to the mmap'ed region one by one. When I read back the written address immediately after write I get back the correct data. But when I read back the data after writing the entire chunk, what I get is the repetition of the last 16 written addresses. I use `O_SYNC` to open `/dev/mem` and use `MAP_SHARED` for `mmap`.

What is going wrong here? Is this some sort of caching issue?

Comment: From that, it sounds a lot more like your peripheral either isn't decoding addresses properly, or simply doesn't have all the appropriate lines wired up. It's highly unlikely to be a Linux problem.

Comment: There was indeed a problem in the FPGA. The write depth in Block memories were incorrect (too small) so I was reading more than I was supposed to.